# Regex Expressions in Spotfire

Tags: regex, spotfire

I'm trying to use RXExtract as a calculated column to dissect *[column1]* by it's values. *[column1]* looks like "location- 1234 (abc)" and I'd like to just separate the "1234" out of it.

My current code in Spotfire is **RXExtract([SM Code], '(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)', 1 )** but I get an "invalid escape sequence error". Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try double escaping the backslashes `RXExtract([SM Code], '(\\d)(\\d)(\\d)(\\d)', 1 )`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RXExtract([SM Code], '\b\d{4}\b', 1)
```

this will match any four consecutive or unconsecutive digits.